# HttpURLConnection timeouts in built jar file

Tags: java, httpconnection

I wrote program that gets a file information in java and shows information in a GUI. when I running program with usage of NetBeans it works correctly, but when I build it's jar file I face connection timeout error. here's code :

```
private void btnFileAddressActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        btnSendForDownload.setEnabled(false);
        if(txtFileAddress.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "آدرس فایل را وارد نمایید", "هشدار", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null);
            return;
        }
        try {            
            fileAddress = new URL(txtFileAddress.getText());
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) fileAddress.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(30 * 1000);
            fileSize = ((float)(connection.getContentLength()));            
            if(fileSize <= 1024){
                lblVolumeValue.setText(fileSize + " بایت");
            }
            else if(1024 < fileSize && fileSize <= 1024 * 1024){                
                lblVolumeValue.setText(String.format("%.2f کیلوبایت", (fileSize / 1024)));
            }
            else if(1024 * 1024 < fileSize && fileSize <= 1024 * 1024 * 1024){
                lblVolumeValue.setText(String.format("%.2f مگابایت", (fileSize / (1024 * 1024))));
            }
            else{
                lblVolumeValue.setText(String.format("%.2f گیگابایت", (fileSize / (1024 * 1024 * 1024))));
            }
            lblStatueValue.setText(String.valueOf(connection.getResponseCode()));
            lblFileExtensionValue.setText(txtFileAddress.getText().substring(txtFileAddress.getText().lastIndexOf(".") + 1, txtFileAddress.getText().length()));
            lblPortionSizeValue.setText(String.valueOf((int)fileSize / downloadersCount) + " B");
            lblRemainValue.setText((String.valueOf(((int)(fileSize)) % downloadersCount)) + " B");
            lblFileNameValue.setText(txtFileAddress.getText().substring(txtFileAddress.getText().lastIndexOf("/") + 1 , txtFileAddress.getText().lastIndexOf(".")));
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "هشدار", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage(), "هشدار", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null);
        }
    }
```

What's the problem with my connection? Why it timeouts in the built jar file?

**Edit**

here is the [image](http://upload7.ir/uploads//71aab11185da3e2b2b3a17514fbc6a46263c6ce2.png) link for built running jar

and here is the [image](http://upload7.ir/uploads//5ba2655b9ba38cf6ef4bc85e828be1994d4dd8ae.png) link for running IDE

Comment: Unless you explicitly set some properties through the IDE, it should work exactly the same way. Time out occures mostly it can't connect to the URL. check the network connection

Comment: no the connection is ok. please check my edit

Comment: I can't read arabic. Are you using any libraries for the program?

Comment: Of course I'm Persian :) not arab .No I have not used any libraries. But as you see in  the images, labels have value in second image which means connection is ok and file information has retrieved, but labels does not have value in first image and face me with timeout error

Comment: Try to debug the code and see what is happening

Comment: Thank you buddy, In the IDE it runs without problem :) . I should debug the executable jar file .

Comment: yeah, try to debug the jar

Comment: Thank you buddy :) . It needs administrator privilege . And by using the CMD It runs correctly .